# Get method in meteor js

Tags: javascript, meteor

In meteor js i have a get function just as:-

```
localhost:3000/profile?user=rishav
```

Now i want to retrieve this value of user in meteor js template.In case of post data we can use event.target.blah.value; where blah is the id.But how to do in case of get data

Comment: it depends on your router. the Meteor guide has some guidance here: https://guide.meteor.com/routing.html

Comment: What router are you using? Iron-router? Flow-router?

Comment: Also in Meteor your route would look like `/profile/:_id` instead of the pattern above. Meteor doesn't use traditional URL parameters.

Comment: i am using iron router

Answer (score 0):

With Iron Router:

> Router.current().params._id

With Flow Router:

> FlowRouter.getParam(":_id")

If you are using multiple parameters you need to be specific in which one you want to retrieve.